# Catch the event when a phone call or some other event shuts off the music player iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I am writing an app that plays music in an AVPlayer and I want to catch the event when like a phone call comes in or something else ends the music playing in the background.

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`

Is this the right method to catch when the app is interrupted but what about when the user is done with the phone call is there another method that i can resume my player from where it left off when the phone call is done and the application is set to active again?

Thanks for the help in advance.

EDIT: ANSWER

```
- (void) beginInterruption {
    if (playing) {
        playing = NO;
        interruptedWhilePlaying = YES;
        [self updateUserInterface];
    }
}

NSError *activationError = nil;
- (void) endInterruption {
    if (interruptedWhilePlaying) {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
        [player play];
        playing = YES;
        interruptedWhilePlaying = NO;
        [self updateUserInterface];
    }
}
```

This is the answer, as long as you implement the AVAudioSession delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for audio code, the functions you want to implement in your AVAudioPlayerDelegate are:

```
 - (void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *) player;
 - (void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *) player;
```

Comment: what if i am using an AVPlayer not an AVAudioPlayer? You think the methods are the same?

Comment: oh, sorry, mis-read. no, i'm not aware of any delegate methods in AVPlayer. in AudioSessionInitialize you can pass an interruption handler: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW5